# jquery data-attribute set not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, attributes

I'm trying to find a `'tr'` element with matching `data-title` value and set `data-qty` value for that element.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
var menu_type = data.type;

switch (menu_type) {
  case 'breakfast':
    var menu_selector = '#breakfast-form';
    break;
  case 'snacks':
    var menu_selector = '#snacks-form';
    break;
  default:
    var menu_selector = '#breakfast-form';
}

for (var key in data.order) {
  if (data.order.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var find_row = $(menu_selector).find('tr[data-title="' + key + '"]').data('qty', data.order[key]);
  }
}
console.log(data);
```

`data.order` is an array object with `{Coffee: "1"}`.

And here's my `<tr>` html:

```
<div id="breakfast-form">
  <table class="orderTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr data-qty="9" data-title="Coffee">
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I can see `data-qty="9" `, what's not working?

Comment: i want to update the value, say from `9` to `1`.

Comment: The updated value will not be visible when you inspect the element. But if you log that data then you'll see the updated data.

Comment: I'm using websocket iibrary to update the dom in real-time.. so it should be visible..

Comment: well, it's working with `attr('data-qty', data.order[key]);` though..

Comment: it's working... with `attr('data-qty', data.order[key]);`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. You need to use `.attr` vs `.data` if you want to assign a `data` attribute to an element.

```js
var selectors = {
  breakfast: '#breakfast-form',
  snacks: '#snacks-form'
};

function test(data) {
  var menuType = data.type,
      cssSelector = selectors[menuType || selectors.breakfast],
      menu = $(cssSelector);

  for(var key in data.order){
    menu.find('tr[data-title="' + key + '"]').attr('data-qty', data.order[key]);
  }  
}

test({
  type: 'breakfast',
  order: {
    Coffee: "1"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="breakfast-form">
  <table class="orderTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr data-qty="9" data-title="Coffee">
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the data attribute and the data properties.

The HTML markup attribute is used to set the DOM element properties on parse.
And the `.data()` method accesses the property directly.

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/): *«The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated »*

Run the snippet below and inspect the markup.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  
  var count = $("#test").data("count");
  console.log(count);
  
  count++;
  $("#test").data("count",count);
  
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" data-count="0">Test div</div>
```

If you want to "see" your changes in the markup, you have to update the markup attribute using `.attr("data-whatever", "new value");`.

Inspect the snippet below now.

```js
setInterval(function(){
  
  var count = $("#test").attr("data-count");
  console.log(count);
  
  count++;
  $("#test").attr("data-count",count);
  
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" data-count="0">Test div</div>
```

Note that there is an efficiency price on insisting to "see" the markup updating.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that **data.order is an array of object with `{Coffee: "1"}`**, here the **key** in for-loop will return the index of the array i.e. 0,1,2...

To fix that, you can do something like this:

```
for(var index in data.order) {
   key =  Object.keys(data.order[index])[0];
   value =  Object.values(data.order[index])[0];
   if(data.order.hasOwnProperty(index)){
      var find_row = $(menu_selector).find('tr[data-title="'+key+'"]').attr('data-qty', value);
   }                   
}
```

Also you were using `.data` instead of `.attr`